# In magento2 command bin/magento upgrade not working for my custom module

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade

Created one **module** and **copied files** in `app/code` but when i am doing `bin/magento upgrade` it's entry not showing in `app/etc/config.php` ?

also i tried writing entry in above file manually but when i do `bin/magento upgrade` it is deleting my entry.

Comment: Can you update the module code atleast registration.php and module.xml of your module?

Comment: I am able to see that now. no issues after setup:upgrade. Thanks

Comment: Remove the question then?